# LocalDateTime not serializing based on given serializer registered with JavaTimeModule

Tags: spring-boot, jackson-databind

I'm facing an issue where Spring boot (v2.6.13) is not parsing LocalDateTime based on a registered serializer, the response of LocalDateTime of RestController is always an array of integers.

```
@Bean
public Module javaTimeModule() {
    JavaTimeModule module = new JavaTimeModule();
    module.addSerializer(new CustomLocalDateTimeSerializer());
    return module;
}
```

```
class CustomLocalDateTimeSerializer extends StdSerializer<LocalDateTime> {

    private static DateTimeFormatter formatter =
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

    protected CustomLocalDateTimeSerializer() {
        super(LocalDateTime.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(
        LocalDateTime localDateTime,
        JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,
        SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {

        jsonGenerator.writeString(localDateTime.format(formatter));
    }
}
```

Notes:

- Injecting object mapper and serialize the object returns the correct format.
- I've defined an object mapper annotated with @Primary, but still facing the same issue.
- I want to configure everything globally - don't wanna use @JsonSerialize on each attribute-

**it seems like Spring is using a different object mapper for serializing a method returned object.**

Comment: I pasted your code in a blank new Spring Boot project and I can't reproduce it. Make sure there's no other configuration interferring with your changes.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce it and you were right, everything is working fine on clean project. I'll investigate my own project and check what causing it, if you can give me some hints and tips, I'd be thankful.


thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue and resolved it.

I have a `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` configuration which was overriding the configured object mapper.

I've solved it using following code

```java
private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) 
{
    var converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        
    converters.add(converter);
    super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
}
```